# Does calling onProgressUpdate stop the AsyncTask thread until completed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following threaded tasking running:

```
public class LoadCellTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {

           // 1

            publishProgress();

           // 3

        }
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... params) {

     // Do UI tasks on Main thread
     // 2
}
```

Does the order of this thread go 1,2,3? Or can it actually go 1,3,2?

Will calling onProgressUpdate stop the threaded task until the progress update is complete? Or will it keep running after the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer of first question..

it is not fixed whether the order 1,2,3 or 1,3,2 will occur. because after calling the publishProgress method system handles the occurance of onProgressUpdate method so we can not tell when exactly this will occur. so both the order is possible

answer of second question..

no. the task will be executed uninterruptedly